# .png image not showing in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, png

I have just added a couple of social media icons to my website. They display fine in safari and firefox but not in chrome.

**I found a possible answer might be to do with the way the png file has been saved. Does anyone know why or how this would affect whether chrome is able to display the image? or is it something in my code?**

```css
section #contact .icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  float: center;
  padding: auto;
  margin: 10% auto;
}
section #contact #instagram {
  background-image: url(images/instagram.png);
  background-size: contain;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
section #contact #instagram:hover {
  background-image: url(images/instagram-grey.png);
}
section #contact #facebook {
  background-image: url(images/facebook.png);
  background-size: contain;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
section #contact #facebook:hover {
  background-image: url(images/facebook-grey.png);
}
```

```html
<section class="content" id="contact">

  <a class="anchortag" name="Contact"></a>
  <h3>Contact</h3>
  <!-- email -->
  <p><a href="mailto:emailaddress" aria-haspopup="true">email</a>
  </p>
  <!-- Facebook -->
  <div class="icon">
    <a id="facebook" title="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/" aria-haspopup="true" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
  <!-- Instagram -->
  <div class="icon">
    <a id="instagram" title="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/" aria-haspopup="true" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: could be browser cache. try clearing your cache under settings in chrome

Comment: I would use a sprite instead of individual images. With individual images the hover images are not requested until the time of the hover state. This can cause a flicker while the image is being downloaded during the first hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clearing your browser cache.

Browsers will store parts of websites in memory, or cache, so it can load faster for you the next time you view it.

In Chrome,

- Click on the `More` button (upper right hand corner)
- Select `Settings`
- Search for `cache`
- Select `clear browsing data...`
- Check `images and files`
- Press the `Clear browsing data` button
- Refresh your website

Answer (score 0):

use css like this :

```
       .icon {
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            float: center;
            padding: auto;
            margin: 10% auto;
        }

        #instagram {
            background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/50/000000/fff);
            background-size: contain;
            display: block;
            float: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #instagram:hover {
            background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/50/000000/fff);
        }

        #facebook {
            background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/50/000000/fff);
            background-size: contain;
            display: block;
            float: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #facebook:hover {
            background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/50/000000/fff);
        }
```

IDs in css are meant to be unique so, you don't have to call them from their parents, instead of

```
section #contact #instagram
```

just use

```
#instagram
```